# Migrating from VExim to Postfix

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, migration, exim

I've got a Exim mailserver working, installed and administered with VExim. We want to move to a new machine with more power, and use Postfix instead of Exim.

Is there any way to migrate the user database from one to another? Can we preserve Maildirs with the tons of email we have?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on where your users were stored with exim? If you used PAM you are lucky because Postfix will be able to use it as a backend too. If users are stored in LDAP you will have to adapt your Postfix configuration to the exim schema. If they are in a SQL-DB you will have to manually port the SQl-statements for Postfix. If your users are in plain-text file chances are that you can also use it directly in Postfix as it also supports such files.

As for the Maildirs: Neither Postfix nor Exim deal directly with them. Usually there is a MDA like procmail/maildrop/deliver depending on what kind of IMAP4/POP3 server you are using.

Comment: There is no "the exim schema" -- Exim uses lookups specified in the config file, so adapts to whatever schema you have.

Comment: Exim supports Maildir directly, and Maildir++, so Exim *does* deal directly with Maildir.

Comment: @Phil: I was referring to this OID http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/1.3.6.1.4.1306.html which seems to be reserved for a Exim LDAP schema.

Comment: I'm one of the Exim Maintainers and I'd never heard of that OID before. It's not used anywhere in Exim. There is one mention of it in the list archives and that's someone asking about it. This looks like a rogue registration by someone unconnected with Exim.  AFAIK anything other than 1.3.6.1.4.1 under 1.3.6.1.4 is rogue.